# css transition and transform overflowing into navbar

Tags: css

I am using a combination of transition and transform to make a background image grow on hover in my html.

The problem is that on hover the image scales into the navbar.

The codepen below doesn't show it, but that gap is closed in my actual html, not sure why its not here (could have something to do with the materialize css library I'm using).

https://jsfiddle.net/tva6zbjh/1/

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="brand-logo grow pl-2pct">Free</a>
    <ul id="nav-mobile" class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
      <li><a href="badges.html" class="grow">Badges</a></li>
      <li><a href="sass.html" class="grow">SAAS</a></li>
      <li><a href="sass.html" class="grow">HELP</a></li>
      <li><a href="collapsible.html" class="grow">Other FAQ's</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="grow two-thirds">
</div>

html {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

body {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

nav {
  background-color: #26a69a;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  z-index: 500;
}


.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.02); }

.two-thirds {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Im having trouble and would like some help with getting the image to scale, but only within its container.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this

```css
nav {
  background-color: #26a69a;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', serif;
  z-index: 500;
}
.grow { transition: all .2s ease-in-out; }
.grow:hover { transform: scale(1.5); }

.two-thirds {
  top: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url(http://asgardcursos.com.br/assets/img/blog/c974b82c774d61bc46fcf82913d11994.jpg);
  background-size: cover
}
.container{
  height: 200px;
  width: 150px;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<nav>

</nav>

<div class="container">
  <div class="grow two-thirds">
  </div>
</div>
```